# Find $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \,n\left( {\frac{{{1^{2022}} + {2^{2022}} + ... + {n^{2022}}}}{{{n^{2023}}}} - \frac{1}{{2023}}} \right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, riemann-sum, sums-of-squares

It's ok to find the limit with integral

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{{1^{2022}} + {2^{2022}} + ... + {n^{2022}}}}{{{n^{2023}}}} = \frac{1}{{2023}}$$
Put ${u_n} = \frac{{{1^{2022}} + {2^{2022}} + ... + {n^{2022}}}}{{{n^{2023}}}} - \frac{1}{{2023}}$

Because $\sum\limits_{i = 1} {\frac{i}{{{n^{2023}}}}} $ is decrease when n $  \nearrow  $. Then by using Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

Then

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } n\left( {\frac{{{1^{2022}} + {2^{2022}} + ... + {n^{2022}}}}{{{n^{2023}}}} - \frac{1}{{2023}}} \right)=\lim n{u_n} = \lim \left( {{u_{n + 1}} - {u_n}} \right) = 0$$

But, the key of title is $\dfrac{1}{2}$ not $0$. Can someone help me, thanks

Comment: The questions are subtly different.